# Reset checkbox style to default

Tags: css, checkbox, styles, reset

I have a lot of things in a CSS file that I am using, which is why somehow my checkbox style got screwed up. I have been trying my best to make it appear like normal but I haven't had any luck. Is there any way I can reset the checkbox style to default? I did a F12 in IE and got this as the style.

The "ms-crm-Checkbox" is the class that I am using.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKnXR.png

Comment: Hi there, can you show the real time example so we can identify where exactly the issue. you can try jsfiddle.

Answer (score 11):

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
     -webkit-appearance: checkbox !important;
     -moz-appearance: checkbox !important;
     -ms-appearance: checkbox !important;
     -o-appearance: checkbox !important;
     appearance: checkbox !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You added styles on input tag and checkbox is an input consider add styles on `input.someclass` or `input[type="text"]` not on all input elements
You can also add styles on all checkbox elements

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  /* styles */
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway, I can reset the style to default by doing something in the  "ms-crm-Checkbox" class in the CSS?

Comment: There is no reset of course you can add styles similar to default but each browser adds a little bit different styles. you can only remove borders, align or whatever you think you won't need and you will be close to default